# How to receive mouse press event on clicking QTableWidget?

Tags: qt

I'm having a table with 100 datas. I need to receive mouse press event while clicking on the table.

Here is the code:

```
ui->tableWidget->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);    


bool Dbtable::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        debugLog("# TABLE WIDGET IS PRESSED");
        return ;
    }
}
```

Now the table is not visible.

Could any one help me in solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried returning  `QWidget::eventFilter()`

Comment: no try this : return QWidget::eventFilter(): this kind of event must be "re called"..

Comment: QWidget::eventFilter() should have parameters. So i need to pass obj name and event for using 'eventFilter'.

Comment: So how can i use return QWidget::eventFilter(); Could you pls explain?

Comment: it was a quick version of what you should use.. parameters are the same of eventFilter of your class..

Comment: Thanks for the reply! i put the return statement out side of if-condition and now its working.